# Keyboard hides widgets

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a very complex screen that has two fields to fill out. Unfortunately, when I click on the bottom input field, the keyboard closes the input field itself. Accordingly, the user does not see what he enters. I have tried many options. As a result, I settled on the option with a list. But it doesn't work well either - I can drag down and see what I'm typing, but as soon as I take my finger off the screen, it scrolls back.

Here is my code for exactly the place -

```
return 
                                  ListView(
                                    keyboardDismissBehavior: ScrollViewKeyboardDismissBehavior.manual,
                                shrinkWrap: true,
                                children: [
                                  SizedBox(
                                    width: 100,
                                    height: 100,
                                    child: Image.network(
                                        state.specificPaymentTypeModels.icon),
                                  ),
                                  Container(
                                    margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                        horizontal: 10, vertical: 10),
                                    child: Text(
                                      state.specificPaymentTypeModels.title,
                                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  SizedBox(
                                      width: width / 1.5,
                                      child: Html(
                                        data: state.specificPaymentTypeModels
                                            .description,
                                      )),
                                  state.specificPaymentTypeModels.alias ==
                                              'freedom-pay' ||
                                          state.specificPaymentTypeModels
                                                  .alias ==
                                              'balancekg' ||
                                          state.specificPaymentTypeModels
                                                  .alias ==
                                              'megapay' ||
                                          state.specificPaymentTypeModels
                                                  .alias ==
                                              'odengi'
                                      ? Container(
                                          margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 15),
                                          child: MyTextField(
                                            hint: 'Введите сумму пополнения',
                                            myController: summa,
                                          ))
                                      : Container(),
                                  state.specificPaymentTypeModels.alias ==
                                              'megapay' ||
                                          state.specificPaymentTypeModels
                                                  .alias ==
                                              'balancekg'
                                      ? Container(
                                          margin: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(
                                              16, 10, 16, 0),
                                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                            border: Border(
                                                top: BorderSide(
                                                    color:
                                                        ConfigColor.lightGrey,
                                                    width: 1.5),
                                                bottom: BorderSide(
                                                    color:
                                                        ConfigColor.lightGrey,
                                                    width: 1.5),
                                                right: BorderSide(
                                                    color:
                                                        ConfigColor.lightGrey,
                                                    width: 1.5),
                                                left: BorderSide(
                                                    color:
                                                        ConfigColor.lightGrey,
                                                    width: 1.5)),
                                            color: Colors.white,
                                          ),
                                          child: TextField(
                                            controller: number,
                                            inputFormatters: [maskFormatter],
                                            style: TextStyle(
                                              color: ConfigColor.textBlack,
                                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                                            ),
                                            decoration: InputDecoration(
                                                hintText: '996 (707)-098-995',
                                                hintStyle: TextStyle(
                                                  fontSize: 16,
                                                  color: Colors.grey,
                                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                                                ),
                                                fillColor: Colors.white,
                                                filled: true,
                                                border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                                    borderRadius:
                                                        BorderRadius.circular(
                                                            4),
                                                    borderSide:
                                                        BorderSide.none)),
                                          ))
                                      : Container(),
                                  state.specificPaymentTypeModels.alias ==
                                              'freedom-pay' ||
                                          state.specificPaymentTypeModels
                                                  .alias ==
                                              'balancekg' ||
                                          state.specificPaymentTypeModels
                                                  .alias ==
                                              'megapay' ||
                                          state.specificPaymentTypeModels
                                                  .alias ==
                                              'odengi'
                                      ? InkWell(
                                          onTap: () async {
                                            await context
                                                .read<ReciveTypeCubit>()
                                              ..reciveType(
                                                      number.text == null
                                                          ? '123456789123'
                                                          : '996${maskFormatter.getUnmaskedText()}',
                                                      state
                                                          .specificPaymentTypeModels
                                                          .alias,
                                                      int.parse(summa.text))
                                                  .whenComplete(() async {
                                                context.go('/reciveType');
                                                final prefs =
                                                    await SharedPreferences
                                                        .getInstance();
                                                await prefs.setString(
                                                    'phoneNumberPayments',
                                                    '996${maskFormatter.getUnmaskedText()}');
                                                print(await prefs.getString(
                                                    'phoneNumberPayments'));
                                              });
                                          },
                                          child: Container(
                                            width: double.infinity,
                                            margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 15),
                                            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                                vertical: 12),
                                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                                color: ConfigColor.green,
                                                borderRadius:
                                                    BorderRadius.circular(32)),
                                            child: Text(
                                              'Готово',
                                              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                              style: TextStyle(
                                                  color: Colors.white,
                                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                                                  fontSize: 16),
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                        )
                                      : Container()
                                ],
                              );
```

And here is the code of the entire screen where the scaffold is enabled - https://dpaste.org/ZD4pJ

I've been struggling with this problem all day and can't handle it myself anymore. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1:**

According to your code. You are facing a keyboard overlapping issue.
The solution is that you need to use the `SingleChildScrollView` widget to make the screen `scrollable` when the keyboard is open.

[image]

**Solution 2:**

You can also try using the `keyboardAware` package
you can use the `KeyboardAware` package. you can find it at the pub. dev...
or use your favorite package...A lot of packages exist on the pub dev

Comment: can you include code-snippet instead of code-image